# What is a java.util.EventListener?

Tags: java, event-listener

I can't find the answer to this question.
What is a java.util.EventListener? How does it work?
I have already done some research on google but I only found this, which isn't very clear: a tagging interface that all event listener interfaces must extend.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A listener is a class containing methods that are invoked when certain actions happen.

`java.util.EventListener` is a marker interface(an interface without any methods) that all listeners should implement.

In fact, it does not even add any functionality but it may be helpful with some IDEs and code-analysis tools.

So, if you want to create your own custom event (that you trigger), you need to somehow call all your listener methods when the event occurs.

For example, you can do this like the following:

At first, you create an interface for your listeners that extends `EventListener`:

```
public interface MyListener extends EventListener{
    void onEvent();
}
```

Then, you will need to create a mechanism to register and call all the events:

```
private Collection<MyListener> listeners = new HashSet<>();
public void register(MyListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}
public void eventHappens() {
    for (MyListener listener:listeners) {
        listener.onEvent();
    }
}
```

Then, you can creator a Listener using

```
public class MyListenerImpl implements MyListener {
    private String msg;
    public MyListenerImpl(String data) {
        this.data=data;
    }
    @Override
    public void onEvent() {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

and you can register it using

```
register(new MyListenerImpl("Event occurs"));
```

Whenever a `eventHappens()` is called(you can call it if you e.g. receive a network packet), all your registered listeners will be executed.

For example:

```
register(new MyListenerImpl("listener 1 called"));
register(new MyListenerImpl("listener 2 called"));
System.out.println("calling event");
eventHappens();
```

would print

> calling event
>
> listener 1 called
>
> listener 2 called

Comment: `MyListenerImpl` should implement the `MyListener` interface

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks.     You can also "constructor inject"  the "Collection<MyListener> listeners"  into your class as another option.

Comment: Yes, this is possible with frameworks like Spring. However, in most cases, you probably don't need a collection containing all listeners registered as beans in your application (unless for diagnostic purposes or similar I guess) but only listeners corresponding for certain kinds of events.

Answer (score 2):

The first Google hit is [the EventListener documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html), as you seem to have discovered.

See that blue navigation bar at the very top of the page?  The fourth word is a “Use” link.  Go to that.

EventListener provides typesafe polymorphism.  For example, java.awt.Component has a [getListeners method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getListeners%28java.lang.Class%29) which requires a subclass of EventListener.

EventListener is actually part of the [Java Beans specification.](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/)  From section 6.4 of that specification:

> Since the new Java event model is based on method invocation we need a way of defining and grouping event handling methods. We require that event handling methods be defined in *EventListener* interfaces that inherit from *java.util.EventListener.* By convention these *EventListener* interfaces are given names ending in “Listener”.
>
> A class that wants to handle any of the set of events defined in a given *EventListener* interface should implement that interface.